# Python3 Whatsapp + Selenium - "Click" Object not callable

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I'm having trouble clicking on people's names within whatsapp.

The error is:
`TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not callable`.

My code:

```
person = 'Tom'

click = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//span[contains(@title,"{person}")]')
click()
```

I also tried

```
click = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//span[contains(@title,"{person}")]/parent::*')
```

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: Sorry have updated to include the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `click()` won't work because `click` is a webElement, not a function. It should be like

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//span[contains(@title,"{person}")]')
element.click()
```